# Couchbase compaction settings via API

Tags: couchbase

I'm trying to change Couchbase Servers compaction settings via the API. Specifically I want to set the time window that compactions can run. Doing this via the web console is trivial but I need to do it via a script and I can't figure out the syntax. I can change other values like the purge interval:

```
curl -u <adminuser>:<password> -d 'parallelDBAndViewCompaction=false&purgeInterval=3' <IP>:8091/controller/setAutoCompaction
```

But the values for allowedTimePeriod just get ignored. Has anyone been able to get this to work?

*EDIT*

Got it working, thanks!

You have to give all five values and the parallelDBandView value:

```
curl -u admin:password -d 'parallelDBAndViewCompaction=false&allowedTimePeriod[fromHour]=0&allowedTimePeriod[fromMinute]=0&allowedTimePeriod[toHour]=2&allowedTimePeriod[toMinute]=0&allowedTimePeriod[abortOutside]=false' ip:8091/controller/setAutoCompaction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the [Compaction API](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/compaction-rest-api.html) documentation but the syntax looks out of date - from the [source](http://src.couchbase.org/source/xref/3.0.3/ns_server/src/menelaus_web.erl#3282) I can see that the four parameters you need are:

```
allowedTimePeriod[fromHour]
allowedTimePeriod[fromMinute]
allowedTimePeriod[toHour]
allowedTimePeriod[toMinute]
```